# changing the position of a file to another in perl

Tags: perl

I have a .dta file which contains below output

```
1600000000000   00000000000   060218                                    BOSTON       MA 15000060000000000000000F5466160239558164
1600000000000   00000000000   060718                                    BOSTON       MA 15000070000000000000000N379809904781009
1600000000000   00000000000   060818                                    BOSTON       MA 15000080000000000000000N372512000987069
1600000000000   00000000000   060918                                    BOSTON       MA 15000090000000000000000F5466307589134928
```

The field "BOSTON" starting position is 74 and ending position is 80, it's length is 6. I want to write the column which is having "BOSTON" from the .dta file to another file, but the position will be different. For eg : The second file in which i want to write should have the column which is having "BOSTON" from starting postion 10 and ending position 16.
Since i am new to perl. Can anybody help me out with that?

Comment: This is pretty straightforward, but I wonder if we don't have an XY problem on our hands. What are you actually trying to accomplish? If you're just reordering columns, then `split`/`join` will work nicely. If you're wanting specific fixed widths, then take a look at `format` in the perl docs. But either way - give it a try, and let us know what you're getting stuck on.

Comment: I am just stuck on with the code. I just want to write that "BOSTON" starting from 74 and ending on 80 to another newly created file to a position starting from 10 and ending on 16

Comment: i just need help with the code since i am new to perl

Comment: If you need help with your code, you should start by showing us the code you've got. Please [edit] the question and include it.

Answer (score -1):

```
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my @fields = unpack('A16 A14 A42 A13 A3 A*', $_);
   say pack('A? A? A? A? A? A*', @fields[0,1,2,3,4,5]);
}
```

Of course, you'll need to replace the `?` and perhaps change the order of the indexes to meet your unspecified format.

Comment: i need to understand this. What is  unpack('A16 A14 A42 A13 A3 A*', $_); and 
 say pack('A? A? A? A? A? A*', @fields[0,1,2,3,4,5]); exactly doing ?